# duvida com query em sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Tenho uma tabela com 5 campos:

- id
- nome
- cargo
- salario
- data

...e queria fazer uma query que retornasse o nome das pessoas com o maior salário, de cada cargo, sendo que tenho por exemplo 3 cargos: analista, dev e engenheiro.

Com esse script consigo trazer o maior salário por exemplo do cargo ANALISTA, mas como trazer dos outros dois, sendo que essa tabela não tem relacionamento?

```
SELECT nome, cargo, salario from vendedor
where salario = (SELECT max(salario) from vendedor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com o `NOT`

```
SELECT *
  FROM vendedor t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM vendedor t2
                   WHERE t2.cargo = t.cargo
                     AND t2.nome <> t.nome
                     AND t2.salario > t.salario);
```

> [`EXISTS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189259(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Quando uma subconsulta é apresentada com a palavra-chave `EXISTS`, a subconsulta funciona como um teste de existência. A cláusula `WHERE` da consulta externa testa se as linhas retornadas pela subconsulta existem. A subconsulta não produz de fato nenhum dado; ela retorna um valor `TRUE` ou `FALSE`.

Comment: o que significa esse (select 1??) deu certo a consulta troquei os parametros da coluna etc...

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo o `SELECT 1` é só pra obrigar algum resultado caso a `query` seja satisfeita, já que o resultado não interfere em nada. O segredo do funcionamento é o `EXISTS`. Vou colocar uma referência sobre ele na resposta

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo coloquei no SQLFiddle a query funcionando junto com outro exemplo possível: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afd0c/5

Comment: @Sorack obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria dessa forma:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, posicao = row_number() over (partition by cargo order by salario desc) 
    from pessoas
    ) a
where posicao = 1
```

A subquery aí vai agrupar pelo cargo e ordenar de forma decrescente pelo salário, criando um campo `posicao` para cada registro.

Na query de fora, eu limito o resultado para apenas os itens com a posição 1.

Se você quisesse trazer os top 10 de cada grupo, bastaria utilizar `where posicao <= 10`.